# Can I use a custom Django manager on a given set of objects?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have some queryset logic that I would be happy to have in a Manager. I already have the objects in an existing queryset, and I would just like to reorder them. I am thinking of doing something like this:

```
class WorkdayManager(Manager):

    def ordered_by_time_available(self):
        results = self.annotate(
            remaining=(F('duration') * 60) - Coalesce((Sum('records__minutes_planned')), 0)
        )
        return results.order_by(['-remaining'])
```

And I would like to use it like this:

```
workday_objs.ordered_by_time_available()
```

Would this work? Or should I be using something different?

Comment: In that case you should subclass the `QuerySet`, and add it to (both) the queryset and the mananger. See for example: https://gist.github.com/allanlei/1090982

Comment: Thanks, would this approach require a fixed queryset or would I be able to use a dynamically created one?

Comment: Never mind, I think I understand now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach seems to be working:

```
from django.db.models import QuerySet


class WorkdayQueryset(QuerySet):

    def ordered_by_time_available(self):
        results = self.annotate(
            remaining=(F('duration') * 60) - Coalesce((Sum('records__minutes_planned')), 0)
        )
        return results.order_by('-remaining')


class Workday(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = WorkdayQueryset.as_manager()
```